# What is the meaning of Username within HDFS console in Ranger?

Tags: apache-ranger

This is Snapshot of Ranger Console

[image]

What is the meaning of Username within HDFS console in Ranger?

Answer (score 1):

The config you are looking at is for ranger to connect to hdfs, so when you create policies and mentioning resource path, existing list will generate.

Ranger will use the username mentioned in the filed to connect to hdfs and satisfy the autocomplete feature.